# runserver_plus for django gives 302 on static files

Tags: python-3.x, django, manage.py, django-extensions, django-static

I'm running manage.py runserver_plus for a django based application, normal runserver works fine but when i use runserver plus all the static files needed by the app give 302.

```
"GET /static/css/base.css?v2.6.6 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/select2-4.0.5/css/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/select2-bootstrap-0.1.0-beta.10/select2-bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/css/base.css%3Fv2.6.6 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/select2-bootstrap-0.1.0-beta.10/select2-bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/select2-4.0.5/css/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/select2-4.0.5/js/select2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /static/clipboard-2.0.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/bootstrap-3.4.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/select2-4.0.5/js/select2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /static/js/forms.js?v2.6.6 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/clipboard-2.0.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
"GET /login/?next=/static/js/forms.js%3Fv2.6.6 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I have tried changing the BASE_DIR path in settings.py and also changed the STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL to see if that fixes the issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html
It says that This item requires that you have the Werkzeug WSGI utilities installed.

Comment: I already have Werkzeug==1.0.1 and it is still not able to load the static files. I can load it in insecure mode but not with ssl